# Symfony 4.1 Environment Variables in functional tests / insulate env variables

Tags: symfony, testing, symfony4

My use case it the following scenario:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/insulating_clients.html

createClient() creates a new Kernel for every call. It reboots the kernel (between requests).

Now with the new environment variables system in symfony4, I ran into problems. My Kernel depends on an environment parameter "tenant". Because of the nature of environment variables in symfony 4.x the env variable is read everytime the kernel is booted.

So when I create new Kernels in a row, the env variable will change its value when (re)bootet.

How would I freeze the environment variables in the kernel? Or how would I overwrite the mechanism of reading the env variable from "env" at all. 
E.g. I want to prepare the kernels so that the env-variables in the config aren't read from real environment, but from an array saved in the instance of the kernel, etc.

Overwriting \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\EnvVarProcessor seems to be a good trick, but this service is created and cached on container compiles, where would i inject my insulated env parameters?

$client->insulate() does not work either (and I don't want to use that)

Comment: Am I right that your problem is that you don't want to read real env variables, you want to specify other especially for test? If so, you can set your local test variables in `phpunit.xml.dist`

Comment: I got one variable that needs to be set for x > 2 Kernels in my functional tests. I cannot use phpunit.xml because every kernel would have the same value for the env var. The value of the envvar differs for every kernel

Comment: What about setting env vars before calling `createClient` via `putenv`?

Comment: On the second request with the client the kernel will be rebooted and will then read (the now changed) env var via $_ENV or getenv again and get a wrong value. I somehow need to "seal" the env var. I have to reboot because I need to reset third party library-depencies.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Nikita Leshchev in the comments, you have to set the environment variable before calling `createClient()`. In order to "seal" the env var in the current test so that your change doesn't affect other tests, you'll have to set it back to what it was when your test finishes.

You can use `putenv()`, `$_ENV` or `$_SERVER` to set and reset the env var, though I wouldn't recommend `putenv()` because you have to deal with typecasting and if the variable is not defined:

```php
public function testWithPutenv(): void
{
    // Save what the env is currently
    // You probably want to manually cast it to the type you need
    // This will return false if the env var is not set
    // which can't really be handled very well
    $originalEnv = getenv('MY_ENV_VAR');

    // Set the env to what you need
    putenv('MY_ENV_VAR=foo');

    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request('POST', '/do-something');

    // assertions...

    // reset the env to what it was before
    putenv(sprintf('MY_ENV_VAR=%s', (string) $originalEnv));
}

public function testWithENV(): void
{
    // Save what the env is currently
    // Have a default if it's not set
    // Alternatively you can check whether it's set or not and 
    // use `unset` to "reset" it at the end of the test
    $originalEnv = $_ENV('MY_ENV_VAR') ?? 'bar';

    // Set the env to what you need
    $_ENV['MY_ENV_VAR'] = 'foo';

    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request('POST', '/do-something');

    // assertions...

    // reset the env to what it was before
    $_ENV['MY_ENV_VAR'] = $originalEnv;
}

public function testWithENV(): void
{
    // Save what the env is currently
    // Default to empty string, so we know whether we need to unset it
    $originalEnv = $_SERVER('MY_ENV_VAR') ?? '';

    // Set the env to what you need
    $_SERVER['MY_ENV_VAR'] = 'foo';

    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request('POST', '/do-something');

    // assertions...

    // reset the env to what it was before
    if ('' === $originalEnv) {
        unset($_SERVER['MY_ENV_VAR']);
    } else {
        $_SERVER['MY_ENV_VAR'] = $originalEnv;
    }
}
```